# Cucumber framework creation

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd

I'm about to start a new gig where the expectation is to set up a testing framework to allow delivery of new features using Cucumber. While I am familiar with automation and creation of feature files, creating the framework from scratch will be a task I've not done before. Thrown into the deep end here.

Before we get into BDD to deliver the new features there is an expectation to get exciting system behaviours written up as features and automated. Before I run too far ahead I want to make sure I am on the right line of thinking of how to start this task.

I am thinking that I start with the feature files and then my step defs and then write some code to execute these steps. Regarding the code structure, would I still have a separate package of classes for pages and a separate class for tests? Or is the best approach to just have a package for page classes that contain all things we can do with the page?

Any resources to help with this initial set up structure?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for SO because it's about advice rather than a specific programming problem. I would ask this in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @JeffC I didn't even know about SQA so I will ensure I look there as well as SO before asking new questions.

Answer (score 2):

Using Cucumber should not impact the way you manage your code in any way. So whatever you have and used to is fine. The only thing you need to add is the "glue" code which is a kind of a mediator class that translates the Cucumber steps into actual classes and methods and then executes them.

So, generally you start with the feature files without thinking about the implementation at all. This is crucial as it helps you to decouple your business logic from the implementation which is the whole point of using Cucumber in the first place. Next step is to run the feature files using the Cucumber runner and it will automatically suggest you what names should be given to "glue" classes methods to be matched to the steps.

For example, say you created the following step in your feature file:

```
I have logged in to the system
```

since it was not yet implemented, if you attempt to run the scenario, Cucumber will throw an exception:

```
cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
```

But it will also suggest how the step implementation should look like for this feature step. So in this case:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^I have logged in to the system$")
public void i_have_logged_in_to_the_system() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

The last step is to implement these methods and here you can reuse any implementation you wish.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. So as I am starting here with nothing, my initial thought was to start writing the page classes and test classes and work back to feature files. But it sounds like I actually need to reverse this and start from feature files and let cucumber do some of the lifting for me in terms of creating step defs. Makes sense.

Comment: @Matt Correct. This is called an outside-in approach and this way you and your business team concentrate on what to develop rather than how and potentially save precious time.

Answer (score 1):

From what i know, the structure should be like below -

```
+---.idea
+---main
|   +---java
|   +---resources
\---test
|   +---java
|   |   \---stepdefs
|   |   |   |---ServiceHooks.java
|   |   |   |---StepDefinitions.java
|   |   |---TestRunner.java
|   \---resources
|       \---features
|           |---LoginProfile.feature
|           |---UpdateProfile.feature
|---pom.xml
|---testng.xml
```

Ref : https://medium.com/agile-vision/cucumber-bdd-part-2-creating-a-sample-java-project-with-cucumber-testng-and-maven-127a1053c180

Comment: The OP never mentioned that he uses Java

Comment: Thanks for this. The question around structure was more around the structure of the code used to either drive or test the system so the methods that the step defs will call. Traditionally I would create a folder for page classes which drive the system and a folder for test classes which assert against the state of the system. Would I need to separate in this way for a cucumber delivery as well?

Comment: @EugeneS It was a good assumption! I am using Java. Sorry, should have stated this.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Eugene S - the point of using Cucumber feature files is to describe the behaviour of the system, not the implementation (you'll find over time that it's easier to maintain that way).
The structure described by @Confused kangaroo is also pretty standard (you'll get the same/similar structure if you start your project as a Maven project. Note the .idea folder is IntelliJ specific).

In addition to these answers, I'd highly recommend "The Cucumber for Java book" (if you're using Java), or "The Cucumber book" (if you're using Ruby). These books describe how to best use Cucumber ans why, including how to set it up to get the most benefits and keep your test trustworthy and maintainable.
Finall, there are plenty of ways to interact with the Cucumber community, as you can find on the Cucumber website (https://cucumber.io/support - the Slack channels are most active atm.)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18550970)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Good point, I've clarified that you can find support options on the Cucumber website.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using java here I've created a skeleton for Selenium-Cucumber framework, you can build atop it:

https://github.com/far11ven/Selenium-CucumberJUnitFramework

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot for taking the time to do this.